# textarea input do not set to empty string after I click the button, and text area cursor do not start from begining

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, socket.io, emoji

[This is my original outlook:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXx5T.png)
This works well with no issue. Here is my original code: 
Related css:

```
.message_write {
    border-top:  3px solid #000 ;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.418) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}

    .message_write textarea.form-control {
        height: 70px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

.chat_bottom {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 13px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Inside group.hbs

```
                              <form  id="message-form" method="post">
                                  <input type="hidden" id="groupName" value={{name}}>
                                 <input type="hidden" id="sender" value={{user.username}}>
                                 <div id="emoji"></div>
                                  <textarea class="form-control nes-textarea" name="message" id="msg" placeholder="Type a message"></textarea>

                                  <div class="chat_bottom">
                                      <button id="send-message" class="pull-right btn btn-primary nes-btn is-primary">
                                          Send
                                      </button>
                                  </div>
                              </form>
```

Inside groupchat.js: So I emit message from client side.

```
    $('#message-form').keydown((e) => {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if(keyCode === 13 ){
            console.log("I just pressed enter")
            e.preventDefault();
            sendMessage();
        }
    })

    // we emit event from client, so we need to go to server to listen event
    $('#message-form').on('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        sendMessage();
    })

    function sendMessage(){
        var msg = $('#msg').val();
        console.log(msg)
        if (msg !== ""){
            socket.emit('createMessage', {
                text: msg,
                room,
                sender
            }, function(){
                $('#msg').val('');
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is what I did to add emojionearea.js :
After I added

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $("#msg").emojioneArea();
});
```

I then use developer tools to check elements:
It becomes following elements
[html after I add emojionearea.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7THrQ.png)

Now, my textarea looks like this:
[after I add emojionearea.js into textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtX2d.png) 
First issues: The textarea is no longer start from beginning of the box, it always start at letter m. And I could not even click or move my cursor to the beginning of the box. 
Second issues: After I click send button, it no longer reset textarea to empty string. My previous work could reset textarea.  It still could output whatever I type in the textarea, but it just no longer reset it.And when I try to use enter to print the message. It do capture keydown event but in the sendMessage() , console.log(msg) return empty string.

Thanks for any help!  Here is  [emojionearea.js](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea) I used.

Answer (score 0):

1. Looks like "emojionearea" has its CSS which makes the text in your text area aligned center, to overwrite it add:

```
   #msg {
      text-align: left;
   }
```

Make sure it comes after the "emojionearea" CSS files or add "!important" statement right after the word "center" (and space between them).

2. Try to add an event function that will reset your form:

```
   $("#send-message").on("submit", function () {
        $("#message-form").reset();
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I follow your instructions, it help me solve first problem. For second problem, I use $("#message-form")[0].reset(); instead of $("#message-form").reset(); But it still didnt reset anything.

Comment: Thanks for your response, try to set the inputs values to empty strings like: $("#message-form input").val(""); and the same for textarea